# Why does setting view width and height not suffice to enforce full browser window rendering of SVG element?

Tags: html, svg

**PROBLEM**

I have the following html, in which I am attempting to draw an SVG viewport containing a line the size of my browser window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    style="outline: 5px solid red" width="100vw" height="100vh">
        <line x1="0" y1="75%" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black"/>
    </svg>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, when I render the html the viewport appears to be larger than my browser window as I must scroll to see the full extent of my SVG viewport as shown below:

[image]

**GOAL**

My goal is to get the viewport to be exactly the size of my browser window as follows:

[image]

**ATTEMPTING USE OF BORDER-BOX**

The border-box redefines the `width` to include padding, border and margins. If the width and height is set to 100vw and 100vh under border-box behavior, that should include all padding, border and margins in the full browser window. However this does not seem to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      svg {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: 5px solid red;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <line x1="0" y1="75%" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" />
      </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

**ADDING BLOCK ELEMENT BEHAVIOR**

According to one of the answers below svg's [act as inline elements by default](https://martin-becker.net/blog/svgs-are-inline-elements/#:%7E:text=SVGs%20are%20inline%20elements%20%E2%80%93%20Martin%20Becker). That's fine, but then simply including `display: block` in the css should fix the issue, however this doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            svg {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 5px solid red;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <line x1="0" y1="75%" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

**OBJECTIONS TO SOME ANSWERS**

1. I don't see why using `%` units is imperative here. `%` simply provides a relative length *with respect* to the parent element, which in this case is `body`. `vw` and `vh` provide lengths relative to the *viewport window* as explained in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp). In this particular application I care more about the viewport window rather than the body element itself...
2. I don't see why setting the margin of the body element to 0 is necessary here. The body element contains the svg block, but since the svg block is defined in terms of view heights and widths that should result in independent width and height behavior from the body element.

Comment: Using `%` units instead of `vw` and `vh` in the CSS works for me

Comment: Using `%` gets the svg to take up the full width, but not the full height.

Comment: @user32882 HTML pages by default have `margin: 8px` and you're getting overflow because your SVG element is 100% screen width while the body can only contain elements that are "100vw - 16px" or "100% viewport width - margin left and right". You can use `width: calc(100vw-16px); height: calc(100vh-16px);` but you're chasing after a body margin that most people set to 0. `width: 100%` calculates relative to parent while `100vw` gets an absolute value based on screen size -- they are two vastly different values. Alternatively, use `svg {margin: -8px}` to offset but this is considered a hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take away `margin` for the `body` tag.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Replace the type of display of the `svg` border with a `border` so as not to violate the nominal size of `svg`. Set the width to  `width: 100%`. And make the `svg` blocky by setting `display: block`.

```
svg {
    display: block;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

svg {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <line x1="0" y1="75%" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

To get the result as in your screenshot, set the height using the `calc()` function to subtract the *upper - 8px* and *lower - 8px* margins of the `body` tag equal to **16 px**:

```
height: calc(100vh - 16px);
```

```css
svg {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 16px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <line x1="0" y1="75%" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain why it is necessary to set the `body` margin to 0 for this to work? Also why can't I just set the `display` type to `block` in my `svg` element instead of nesting in a new `div` element?

Comment: @user32882, I did without div, but my solution is not completely ready yet.

Comment: I was ideally looking for a solution which would only manipulate the `svg` element....

Comment: You still appear to be manipulating the parent `body` element. I do not see why this is necessary. Please see edit to my original question.

Comment: @user32882, Check out my second snippet, pls.

Answer (score 1):

SVG elements are displayed inline by default.

add in your css, and check result

```
svg {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: calc(100vw - 10px - 8px);
  height: calc(100vh - 10px - 8px);
  display: block;
}
```

[source](https://martin-becker.net/blog/svgs-are-inline-elements/#:%7E:text=SVGs%20are%20inline%20elements%20%E2%80%93%20Martin%20Becker)

Comment: It's good to know that svg elements are block elements. I don't see however why I have to set `margin` to 0 for the `body` element. Using `border-box` along with `100vw`/`100vh`should be sufficient no?

Comment: by default body contains some margin, so when we apply 100vh or 100vw then that margin cause of page scroll

Comment: The margin should be taken care of by forcing `border-box` behavior. There should be no need to tinker with the `body` element

Comment: `border-box` will work if you use % instead of `vh` or `vw`

Comment: no it doesn't. Please check edit to original question

Comment: now you are facing this issue due to `height: 100%`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: here is full css example: `svg {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 5px solid red;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        display:block;
      }
      
body {
 margin: 0
}`

Comment: You must need to normalize body margin.

Comment: Again, I don't see why that should be necessary. I want to keep my padding, border and margin for my `svg` element. I don't want to depend on the parent element...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230076/discussion-between-zia-ur-rehman-and-user32882).

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome's developer tools came in extremely handy here. Highlighting the `body` and `svg` elements in the DOM and inspecting the items in the browser showed the following:

- The `body` element has a default margin >0, but the default border and padding appears to equal 0.
- The `svg` element has a default margin and padding equal to 0.
- The default border for the `svg` element is nonzero here, hence the need for `border-box` behavior when assigning `width` and `height` of the viewport

The browser was basically appending a nonzero default margin from the `body` element to the 100 view heights and view widths that I was assigning to the `svg` element. So it makes sense that, with my initial code, a scrollbar was appearing.

Forcing a zero margin on the `body` element removes all extraneous white space around my SVG content, and as @s.kuznetsov and @Zia Ur Rehman indicated, this results in the desired output. This is the code I ended up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0;
            }
            svg {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 5px solid red;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <line x1="0" y1="75%" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="black" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

I believe this answer clarifies ***why*** I was getting a scrollbar in the first place, contrarily to the other answers. However, I will accept one of the other answers as a courtesy and because they allowed me to understand what was going on in my code.